# The accepted answer of the Ask Different example question is wrong!

Tags: bug, feature-request, status-completed

The [about page](https://apple.stackexchange.com/about) for Ask Different uses [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/37465/is-it-possible-to-read-ibooks-without-an-ios-device):

[image: screenshot]

The problem is, the answer, as of a few months ago is YES. Apple released iBooks support in the newest version of OS X: Mavericks.

[image: Mavericks iBooks]

There is an answer on that page, by Jason S, which is correct, but it only has 2 upvotes and the accepted answer now has 18 upvotes. I think it'd be a good idea to change the question exampled there.

<sub>[See also: my question on meta.SO about a bunch of /about problems.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/211188/some-problems-with-about-pages)</sub>

Comment: Great eye! I vaguely recall wondering what happens to change that. Let me check on it...

Comment: I was going to say that I totally don't remember answering an iBooks question. Haha.

Answer (score 1):

Alright.  I have selected a new question and will ask people to comment here or answer if they would like to nominate another question (or type of question) for the about page. We can't choose any question, but have several dozens to pick.

Additionally, since we liked the question that was being featured enough to feature it, I've placed a bounty to see if we can get a better answer. I probably will bounty the current question to see if we can get a better answer and remind me to check on it in a week to be sure it still shows well on the about page.

Comment: the "accepted" answer on that post actually has one vote on the real post. [See the real question](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/40355/can-i-see-which-ipad-apps-i-use-most-frequently) and the [about page](http://apple.stackexchange.com/about)

Comment: @JakobWeisblat yes. See the bounty notice I added. :) I hope people will vote up e correct answer and possibly also change the accepted answer if necessary..

Comment: Bounties are post notices and they, along with comments get stripped on the about page for clarity can cleanliness. See the featured question list for the next 7 days to observe the bounty. Also, the part of about that explains comments preserves them. I really like how our current example shows a nice comment as well as people refraining from trivial edits for grammar when the meaning of the answer is clear enough.

Comment: Can we not just edit the accepted answer?

Comment: Anyone can edit it - even anonymous 999 ugg boot spammers (as long as it gets approved in that last case of course). ;)